# Eclipse: Java application size

Tags: java, eclipse

So i made it finally to the final stage of my simple java app that runs under windows and is used to get the user name and log it in an remote excel file. up until now everything is ok.
When i Externelize (does that word exist?) the app to make it a runnable jar the size of the app was 22Mo! wich is huge since i want to use it in an email (outlook).
Here come the question (finally). Can i delete any of the default java jars in the classpath  and the app will still run ?? if yes, which ones?? 
NB: i tried including the imports in the SS if it does help
NB2: the Jar of the app it self is just 20Ko , the ressources are around 22Mo .

By the way thank you all for helping me make this app it was thanks to this website eventhought i didn't ask any question up until now you'll still answered them all..You rock !

Those are my imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;
```

EDIT: So after the discussions i managed to reduce the size of the app to 8Mo by deleting some of the jar in the referenced library (org.ibm.icu.jar). The app still runs perfectly without it

Comment: have you thought about linking to the external libraries in your email? in that case you can send just your part (as a jar) and have your clients download the externals themselves.

Comment: Well i could, but the point of the app was to be just a "click and close" process. it will be much troublesome if i forced the clients to download anything , dont you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jar file is just a zip file, so what I would do is simply unzip the file and see what comes with it and what is large. The standard java libraries, should not even be part of your JAR as they are part of the JRE.

However, my suspicion is that you use Apache POI and that is huge. So if you are writing to an Excel file you might have to stick with that size or find another library.

You could for example write the output as CSV which is very lightweight.

Comment: Yes, Apache POI is ~20mb itself.

Comment: I used -indeed- Apache POI however its size is just 2Mo. Other jar files like it were in there too, like com.ibm.icu (10Mo!)and org.eclipse,equinox (8Mo)...ect You said that standard java library shouldnt even be part of the jar?? this is my first so maybe i did something wrong while compiling it??

Comment: These are not what I would consider standard Java Libraries, they seem to come from eclipse, how do you compile? The only jars you should need per the above is POI and SWT.

Comment: From Eclipse: by clicking on the project->Export->Java runnable and following "next" from there

Comment: That sounds about right, do project->Properties->Java Build Path and see and see what you have in there.

Comment: Besides JRE System library (1.6.0 SE) there is like 10 jar files that starts with org.eclipse and the famous Apache POI

Comment: So upon your ealier response i tried removing com.ibm.icu.jar ...the app still worked fine and i have managed to reduce the size to 8Mo ...Now the org.equinox.jar is it mandatory?

Comment: You should try removing it. What happens? The only thing you should need is POI and the SWT jar for your operating system

Comment: Can't delete anymore, the app crashes with a runtime error if i delete any of the remaining jar...Still 8Mo is affordable  Thanks for the help. i'll edit my original comment with the "Solution" :)